# Strange result in c#

Tags: c#

My problem is too strange, Brief :

```
double a = 1 / 2;
MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());
```

It shows `0`
I tried with `decimal` , `float` but it's always `0`

Comment: Because integer division of 1 / 2 is zero. Doesn't matter what you assign zero to.

Comment: you need to understand the difference and way the compiler handle your input! (int) 1 / (int) 2 will have a result of int!

Comment: The moral of the story here is that **the type analysis of an expression is independent of what it is being assigned to** for most expressions in C#. `1/2` does not change in value just because you are assigning it to double. (The exception to this rule is lambdas, which do change their meaning depending on what they are assigned to.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you need to write :

```
double a= 1 / 2.0d;
```

By dividing `int` to `int` compiler produces `int` result and *after* assigns it to `double`.

It's the same like writing:

```
 int resultInt = 1/2;
 double a = resultInt;
```

By specifying in your operation `2.0d` you explicitly manifest your intention to produce `double` after devision.

Comment: Personally I prefer promoting the numerator as it's slightly clearer.

Answer (score 5):

The division is being performed in *integer arithmetic* which means you will lose precision *before* the result is assigned to your `double` type.

Promote one of the literals to a `double` to force the calculation to be performed in *floating point*. i.e. write

```
double a = 1.0 / 2;
```

Answer (score 4):

`1` and `2` are both regarded as integer constants. The result of an `int` divided by an `int` is another `int`, before it is cast to `double`. Indicate to the compiler that at least one of the constants is double by suffixing it with `d`, or providing a decimal point.

e.g.

```
double a = 1d/2d;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

double a = (double)1 / (double)2;

Regards,